# Python Nginx Production Timeout

Tags: python, ubuntu, nginx, uwsgi

I have built a quick bottle app which calls an external API and updates a few fields.  When I run this app on my dev machine it runs for about 3 minutes as the API which it is talking to is rather slow.

When I move the app into our production environment, I am getting a 502 response.  It bombs out exactly 30 seconds after starting.  I beleive this is a timeout.

I followed this guide to setup the environment:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

Anyone have an idea how to increase the timeout on NGinx?  I have tried using setting up the proxy_connect_timeout is the NGinx conf file, but it does nothing to resolve the issue:

```
proxy_connect_timeout   300;
proxy_send_timeout      300;
proxy_read_timeout      300;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It should work by increasing `proxy_read_timeout 600`. in nginx.conf file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try upgrading the timeout for your proxy pass in Nginx by adding:

```
proxy_connect_timeout 75s;
proxy_read_timeout 300s;
```

on `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` or `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` if you want to increase the timeout limit on all sites served by nginx.

You must add --timeout 300 as well to your gunicorn process/config.

This solved my problems in the past with bigger uploads.

Comment: Awesome.  How exactly do I find the gunicorn process/config file?  Also, is uWSGI the same as Gunicorn?

Comment: Both have the same goal but not same.You can refer this to configure gunicorn `http://agiliq.com/blog/2013/08/minimal-nginx-and-gunicorn-configuration-for-djang/`

Comment: You can use this command to run your application in backend in production with uwsgi `uwsgi --http 0.0.0.0:8134 --wsgi-file UniservedWebsite/wsgi.py &` and refer your nginx to `0.0.0.0:8134` and add `http-timeout`

Comment: Amazing. You have saved my lot of time. Thanks for this man. :)